# if else statement for satisfying textbox insert not null and datatype varchar

Tags: c#, if-statement, types

Say I need to satisfy if else statement that

1. CustomerCode must be filled in(not null)
2. CustomerCode must be dataType varchar

How to write if else correctly?
Thanks for any help in advanced, guys!

```
sqlCustomerMaster.InsertParameters["CustomerCode"].DefaultValue =
                                                txtCustomerCode.Text.ToString();
try
{
    txtCustomerCode.Text = "";
    if (txtCustomerCode.Text != null)
    {
        sqlCustomerMaster.Insert();
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the input is from a text box there always should be a mapping to `varchar`, so you just want to check whether the string is null or empty:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCustomerCode.Text))
{
    sqlCustomerMaster.Insert();
}
```

This will guarantee `txtCustomerCode.Text` has at least one character but not whether its numeric etc, but you did not list any other conditions.

Comment: it's also worth noting that the line `txtCustomerCode.Text = "";` in the OP's post would make this `if` check fail every time

Comment: @kaveman: For sure, that one has to go - probably a leftover from testing something?

Comment: Tried and successfully run without problem. I need this but I think it is better by using validation control, right? The problem is, my validation is only checking null, not varchar datatype. I want both validation happens clientside.